HTML Button loses the URL information on Click
This is related to our A-Z Databases which uses the EZproxy links to gain access to subscription databases for the library.
If a user clicks on the edge of the button rather than directly on the text, The initial URL goes from
https://nyit.idm.oclc.org/login?url=https://search.proquest.com/abicomplete?accountid=12917
to
https://nyit.idm.oclc.org/login
This is breaking the user experience so they never get to the database. They get to the EZproxy landing page instead.
How can fix my html code so that this does not happen?
    <section class="ftco-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="popover-header">
                    <h2 class="heading-section">Login to access library resources.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="row ""col-md-7 col-lg-5">
                    <div class="login-wrap p-4 p-md-5">
                <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <img src="public/logo.png" title="Proxy Login" alt="Proxy Login">
                </div>
                <form action="/login" class="login-form" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="form-control btn-primary rounded px-3"><a href="http://nyit.idm.oclc.org:80/login?auth=shib&url=^U" style="color: #ffffff">Login with Okta Verify</a></button>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="form-control btn-primary rounded px-3">
                    <p><a href="http://nyit.idm.oclc.org:80/login?auth=textfile&url=^U" style="color: #ffffff">Login as a Guest.</a></p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                 </div></form>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="popover-footer"><a href="https://www.nyit.edu/policies/privacy_statement" target="_blank">Privacy Statement</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>




The <a> tag isn't allowed as a descendant of the <button> tag (or vice versa). See the content categories and permitted content on MDN. Your HTML is invalid, so it isn't surprising that it doesn't work properly.

If you have accidently created a second account you can request that they be merged by filling out the contact us form. Please make sure you are familiar with What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?


If a user clicks on [...] the button [...] The initial URL goes [...] to https://nyit.idm.oclc.org/login

Look at your form action:
<form action="/login" class="login-form" method="post">

When you click on a button to submit a form, the user is navigated to that form's action URL.  In this case that URL is /login.
You're confusing links and form buttons.  This is not only very unintuitive, it's invalid HTML.  Pick one or the other.
In this case it sounds like you just want to use the links.  If there's no scenario in which you want to submit that form, don't use a form or buttons.  For example:
<div class="form-group">
  <a href="http://nyit.idm.oclc.org:80/login?auth=shib&url=^U" style="color: #ffffff">
    Login with Okta Verify
  </a>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <p>
    <a href="http://nyit.idm.oclc.org:80/login?auth=textfile&url=^U" style="color: #ffffff">
      Login as a Guest.
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

No form, no buttons, no confusion.
I also recommend not using <p>&nbsp;</p> for layout purposes, but left it and your inline styles here to keep the proposed changes only to the problem being solved.  Use CSS to style your layout, not unnecessary HTML elements.
If you want your links to look like buttons, style them to look like buttons.  But don't wrap them in actual buttons, in an actual form, if you don't want to use buttons or a form.
